# Optional Conditional statement in where clause

Tags: sql-server, where-clause, conditional-statements

I need to add a condition in my WHERE clause that will include items in a search if @UserRoleId = 4, else exclude them from the search (SQL Server).

```
INSERT INTO @partData
(
  PartPrefix,
  PartNumber,
  MyProDescription,
  ItemNumber,
  PartType,
  Side,
  VehicleLocation,
  MyProPrice
)
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN LEFT(myParts.MyProDescription, 4) = 'FOIL' THEN 'FOIL'
    ELSE LEFT(myParts.PartNumber, 3)
  END,
  PartNumber,
  MyProDescription,
  ItemNumber,
  PartType,
  Side,
  VehicleLocation,
  MyProPrice  
FROM 
  MyProExport myParts
WHERE
  @year BETWEEN myParts.YearFrom AND myParts.YearTo AND
  myParts.CarMake = @make AND 
  REPLACE(myParts.CarModel, ' ', '') = REPLACE(@model, ' ', '') AND
  (
    myParts.EngineDisplacement = @engine OR 
    myParts.EngineDisplacement = 'ALL'
  ) AND
  LEFT(myParts.PartNumber, 3) NOT IN ('300','400') -- Exclude these parts if not @UserRoleId = 4
```

The last statement needs to be modified to display 300 and 400 only if @UserRoleId is = 4. Else just show 300. I’m confused on how to set this up. I’ve tried:

```
CASE
  WHEN @UserRoleId = 4 THEN LEFT(myParts.Number, 3) NOT IN ('300','400') -- Exclude parts
```

with no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a case statement, just use AND/OR logic.

```
AND (LEFT(myParts.HollanderNumber, 3) = '300'
OR (@UserRoleID = 4 AND LEFT(myParts.HollanderNumber, 3) = '400'))
```

This will always display 300 and only display 400 if the `@UserRoleID = 4`

Comment: It’s working, but only returning 300’s when not UserRoleId is 4 and only returns 400’s when UserRoleId is 4… I also need the rest of the parts that contain other prefixes like ‘200’, ‘500’ (a bunch more) I apologize if my post isn’t sufficient.